# Font Awesome 5 (with CSS) fa-layers

Tags: font-awesome-5

I upgraded to Font Awesome 5 (FA 5) from version 4.7. The reason was the layered icons.
In FA 4.7, `fa-stack` classes were used. In FA 5, fa-layers are much powerful.

The problem, as far as I see, `fa-layers` are only implemented in pure js version of Font Awesome. (using fontawesome-all.js). If you want to use css version, you do not see `fa-layers` class anywhere in folder structure (in the current version of 5.0.8). Is it possible to use fa-layers with css version of FA 5?

By css version I mean this:

```
<head>
  <!--core first + styles last-->
  <link href="/static/fontawesome/fontawesome-all.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Bt Js version, I mean this:

```
<head>
  <!--load everything-->
  <script defer src="/static/fontawesome/fontawesome-all.js"></script>
</head>
```

Since fontawesome-all.js replaced all i tags to svg, css manipulation is difficult with this version. So, if css version has all the features that Js version has, I would like to us css version of FA 5.

Answer (score 6):

No, Webfonts with CSS does not have all of the features that SVG with JS has. The [How to Use SVG with JS](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/svg-with-js) page shows some of the features that are new or exclusive to SVG with JS. [Layers](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/svg-with-js#layering), specifically, are new to SVG with JS:

> Layers are the new way to place icons and text visually on top of each
>   other, replacing our classic icons stacks.

You can still use stacks in Webfonts with CSS to do some interesting things: [codepen example](https://codepen.io/fontawesome/pen/rvvKoY/)

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
  <i class="fas fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fal fa-circle fa-2x fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
  <i class="far fa-triangle fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span>
```

But stacks are definitely not as powerful as Layers with Power Transforms, which are only available in SVG with JS.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer using the Web Fonts version as well, mostly for performance reasons.  I also wanted to use the more advanced layered icons with the `fa-layers` class.

I recreated some of the `fa-layers` functionality in CSS and put the stylesheet [up on GitHub](https://github.com/cityssm/fa5-power-transforms-css).  It's not perfect or complete.  I'm still working on it, but it might help you get some of the missing functionality without switching away from Web Fonts and CSS.